# PDFs Corrupted Rails 5, Nginx, ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried everything and am running out of ideas. Please help.

We have Elastic Beanstalks in AWS deployed with 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.7.1 running Ruby 2.4 (Puma). Running on them is Nginx 1.12.1 and Rails 5.

In a controller I'm downloading a PDF from an API and then attempting to send it along.

```
data = API::StatementPDF.new(id: params[:id]).result
    send_data data.force_encoding('BINARY'),
              :filename => "statement.pdf",
              :type => "application/pdf",
              :disposition => "attachment",
              stream: 'true',
              buffer_size: '4096',
              :x_sendfile => true
```

I've tried with and without `force_encoding`, `buffer_size`, `x_sendfile`. Have tried incresing the buffer size to huge numbers. Tried disabling gzip in nginx in `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/nginx-extensions.conf`

```
# Configure GZIP compression
gzip              off;
gzip_min_length   1100;
gzip_types        application/pdf;
gzip_vary         on;
```

But no matter what I do, the PDF comes thru corrupted, and if I open the file in a text editor, many of the characters aren't encoded correctly.

[image]

On the left is the working PDF, on the right the PDF sent by the Beanstalk / Rails / Nginx server.

The PDFs come thru fine when running the rails server locally. Adding a static PDF into the App and serving it up also causes the file to be corrupted.

```
send_file "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/statement.pdf", type: "application/pdf", x_sendfile: true
```

...so I'm convinced it's a problem with Nginx, Puma or the Elastic Beanstalk. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried placing a PDF in the /public directory and downloading it from the http://root-URL/pdf-name.pdf? This may help you rule in / out Puma. Also, have you tried deploying with Passenger standalone instead of Puma? In terms of fault-finding either of these might help lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Also, are you able to tell if any of the server environment variables are strange? Does LANG or LC_NAME appear anywhere (especially if you ssh to the server, check /etc/profile variables)

Comment: My DevOps team has locked down the Beanstalks so we can't SSH into them. The only ENV variables I can see are injected in by AWS, and LANG ad LC_NAME are not present

Comment: Attempting serving up a PDF from the /public directory - change is building - will update in ~ 10 minutes

Comment: the PDFs come thru blank, the file if I open it in Sublime is a huge block of Hex, not in the format of a working PDF

Comment: Typically nginx serves assets from the /public directory directly without Rails getting involved. That suggests that there is something going on with the nginx configuration that is strange. It is interesting though that your CSS and Javascript assets are served cleanly. Maybe if you check the network response for the PDF (F12 in your browser to get to the debugger then pick the network tab), it might suggest something? Especially the response headers.

Comment: I just re-read your comment. Did you just place a pdf in /public (such as /public/some.pdf) then access it as http://yoursite.com/some.pdf ...Or did you still try to serve it with `send_file`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being with the API Gateway.

- Ruby on Rails
- Puma
- NGINX
- API Gateway

I didn't think there was anything past NGINX.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.  Where exactly did you found that the problem originated from?!

Answer (score 0):

NGINX really doesn't do any sort of weird stuff with the encoding of the binary files.

Moreover, this is very unlikely to be related to http://nginx.org/r/gzip, either, as the [`gzip`](http://mdoc.su/-/gzip.1) compression is done on the [HTTP protocol level](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) (with [`Accept-Encoding` in requests](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_request.h#accept_encoding) and [`Content-Encoding` in responses](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_request.h#content_encoding)), and the resulting download should be presented uncompressed once out of the HTTP context (the same way as HTTP headers aren't included in your downloads, either).

Finally, although perhaps not applicable for `statement.pdf` (presumably, a user-specific one-time-use statement with size comparable to an average web-page), the best practice for serving of downloadable binaries through a proxy server is to use the **`X-Accel-Redirect`** special handling of the proxy server, fully supported by nginx as per http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ignore_headers and http://nginx.org/r/internal, eliminating extra bottlenecks and the inefficiency of serving large files directly with the actual backend.